# Target a specific user - Push Notifications - Backendless

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, backendless

How can I target a specific user with a push notification, triggered from a mobile app, using backendless as BaaS?
Should I save each users DeviceToken and then use it when I want to push a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation. Please see this: https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/rest/messaging_message_publishing.htm

and search for the following section: 
**"Publishing a push notification and targeting specific devices"**

Regards,
Mark

Comment: How do I get the device ID of the user? When I register a user, how do I add the device ID?

Comment: Is this for iOS, Android or Windows Phone?

Comment: iOS and this comment has to be 15 characters long

Comment: For ios you need to use deviceToken, which can be obtained in the AppDelegate events: https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/ios/messaging_device_registration.htm

Comment: The api reference on the website is not clear. I want to get the deviceID of a specific user. How? Do I have to store each users deviceID in the user table?

Comment: Device ID belongs to a device. However, you can store the device ID on the server as a custom user property.

Comment: And how do I fetch the device ID? I couldn't find a function that returns it. Any hints?

Comment: If you take a look at the link for the doc I provided, it should be obvious how to get the deviceToken: https://monosnap.com/file/sMpXa7f5LYRiXKewwbH5wqIQQ1woPK

Comment: Is there a way we could communicate easier? Skype or something similar?

Comment: Of course, please post your questions to our support forum: http://support.backendless.com